# Utilizar <select> con API en JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

Estoy haciendo una pagina web donde estoy utilizando la etiqueta select para diferentes usos de una API que esta en JSON (https://github.com/aunyks/newton-api) y un input para ingresar la informacion, como puedo hacer un if en javascript con los values del select y enviar un POST para parsear el JSON en javascript puro?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas espero esto sea lo que buscas te puse el ejemplo en `jquery` y en `javascript` vanilla

```js
// jquery

$("#select1").change(function(){
  $.get("https://newton.now.sh/derive/"+$(this).val(), function(data, status){
    
  $("#pre").html(JSON.stringify(data))
    });  
})

// javaScript Vanilla

document.getElementById("select2").addEventListener("change",function(){
    $.get("https://newton.now.sh/derive/"+this.value, function(data, status){
        document.getElementById("pre2").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>jquery</h2>
<select name="" id="select1">
  <option value="x%5E2">opcion1</option>
    <option value="x%5E5">opcion2</option>
    <option value="x%5E10">opcion3</option>
</select>
<pre id="pre">
  
</pre>
<br><br>
<h2>javascript vanilla</h2>
<select name="" id="select2">
  <option value="x%5E2">opcion1</option>
    <option value="x%5E5">opcion2</option>
    <option value="x%5E10">opcion3</option>
</select>

<pre id="pre2">
  
</pre>
```